# how to get list data from foreign key to another list of data

Tags: php, database, laravel, arraylist, foreign-keys

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS6Jj.png)

We have 2 tables first table name is attributes_products in which attritubes_id a foreign key of the second table is attributes so we can find the list of second table by using first table

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Right-joining the tables.

```
 SELECT attributes_products.id,attributes.attributes_name,attributes.attributes_type,attributes.attributes_required,attributes.attributes_status
FROM attributes_products
RIGHT JOIN attributes
ON attributes_products.id = attributes.id;
```

For more info-https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_join_right.asp